# Wrong Plot Output

Tags: windows, plot

I am trying to plot the following in gnuplot in Windows,

```
    reset

# png
set terminal wxt size 650,550 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output 'example_plot.png'

set border linewidth 1

#unset key

set xtics auto
set ytics auto

set title 'example plot of 3-resonance K-matrix'
set xlabel 'E(GeV)'
set ylabel 'sigma(1/GeV)'
set xrange [3:6]
set yrange [0:0.15]

gee1 = 1
gDD1 = 1
m1 = 3.9
me = 0.000511
mf = 1.86965

p(x) = sqrt(1-(4*mf*mf/(x*x)))
q(x) = sqrt(1-(4*me*me/(x*x)))

rho(x) = (1/(16*3.14159))*sqrt(1-((4*mf*mf)/(x*x)))

P(x) = ((gee1*gDD1)/(x*x-m1*m1))
K(x) = rho(x)*((gDD1*gDD1)/(x*x-m1*m1)

Fsq(x) = (P(x)*P(x))/(1+(K(x)*K(x)))

f(x) = (3/(64*3.14*x*x))*(p(x)/q(x))*Fsq(x)
plot Fsq(x) title "T^2" with lines linestyle 1
#plot f(x) title "g(s)" with lines linestyle 1
```

but I get the wrong plot. The peak should be at about 31300, but instead mine peaks at about 200.

I really cannot see what is wrong with my code. Could anyone help?

Thanks,
Christian[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeyuE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spike in your function is so sharp that unless you evaluate it directly at the x-coordinate corresponding to the max, the plot will not capture the true maximum.   The more finely you sample the function for plotting (e.g. `set sample 5000`) the more likely that one of the samples will be close to the true maximum, but you cannot guarantee hitting it exactly.
[image]